# Считывание символа во время печати

Tags: c++

Я новичек в c++, но так и не смог найти ответ на свой вопрос в интернете.
Я хочу считывать то что вводит пользователь во время того как он печатает.
Сейчас я получаю введенный текст от пользователя через cin >> variable;
Но проблема в том что такой метод позволяет мне получить пользовательский ввод только после того как пользователь нажал enter. 
Я же хочу отлавливать его ввод на лету. Хочу чтобы как только он нажал кнопку "=" выполнить определенную функцию.
Подскажите как это можно сделать?

Comment: `getch` `getchar` или подобное. Зависит от точного диалекта языка.

Comment: Можно по-подробнее как это реализовать в коде?

Comment: подробнее - ищете нужную функцию, потом `int t; while (t = getch() != -1) {cout << t};` как-то так.

Comment: Несомненно вам стоит указать в чем вы разрабатываете и какого рода это приложение (консольное или диалоговое), т.к. консольные приложения не позволяют простым способом реагировать на нажатия клавиш.

Comment: Приложение консольное. Разрабатываю в Dev-C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
  setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" );
  while(true)
  {
      if(kbhit())
      {
          char knop=getch();
          if (knop == '=')
              cout << "Это =";
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Указывайте ОС к которой относится вопрос. В винде `kbhit()` опрашивает клавиатуру и не ждет нажатия клавиши. Вы в самом деле уверены, что хотите загружать CPU в бесконечном цикле? Обычно достаточно вызывать `getch()`, который возвращает введенный символ не дожидаясь нажатия <Enter>.

Comment: Я еще только разбираюсь с c++. Я пытался сделать это без бесконечного цикла, но у меня не особо вышло. Буду благодарен если отрефакторите

Comment: В своем комментарии (c `while(...getch()...)`) под Вашим вопросом @pavel по сути уже все показал.

Comment: Если только разбираетесь, то khbit вполне хороший вариант. Можете попробовать сделать отдельный поток, который будет опрашивать клавиатуру и слать слать информацию о нажатых клавишах в другой поток, который будет выводить их в консоль. Также можно попробовать использовать PeekConsoleInput, который позволит отслеживать не только клавиатуру.